# Getting PHPUnit 3.7 to work with CakePHP 2.4.5

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

Setup:

- OSX 10 (Yosemite)
- PHP 5.3.28
- CakePHP 2.4.5
- PHPUnit 3.7.32

I've installed PHPUnit (which I can confirm by running "phpunit --version" on the command line) and I've made sure it's location (/usr/local/bin) is included in the 'include_path' in my php.ini file. However, when I visit http://localhost/my-app/test.php, it still says "PHPUnit is not installed!".

I'm at a bit of a loss here. Anyone have ideas on how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart Apache after installing and modifying your php.ini?

Comment: have you tried running tests from the command line?